# How to use Matlab's abstract property and to declare its type in the concrete subclass

Tags: matlab, class, properties, abstract

I am trying to describe that an abstract class AA has an abstract property X of type BB.  This property BB differs for different concrete subclasses of AA.  This BB is also an abstract class, and its concrete subclasses will be used as X for different concrete subclasses of AA.  However, when I tried to do that as the following code, I got an error message.

So first, AA and AA concrete are

```
classdef (Abstract) AA
    properties (Abstract)
        X@BB;
    end
end

classdef AAconcrete < AA
    properties
        X@BBconcrete;
    end
end
```

and BB and BBconcrete are

```
classdef (Abstract) BB < matlab.mixin.Heterogeneous
end

classdef BBconcrete < BB
end
```

When I tried to initiate AAconcrete, I got the following error message.

```
>> a = AAconcrete
Error using AAconcrete
The property 'X' restriction defined in class 'AAconcrete' must match the
property definition in base class 'AA'.
```

I understand that the error message said type BBconcrete is not the same as BB, although `isa(BBconcrete,'BB')` returns true.  Even though if I don't declare X as type BB in the abstract class AA, the same error message appears.

I wonder what's the right way to describe such relationship, and your help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't attempt to make MATLAB a strong typed programming language, that typically does not succeed. Use your base class and (if required) check the data types when writing:

```
classdef AAconcrete < AA
    properties
        X@BB;
    end
    methods
        function set.X(obj,x)
            assert(isa(x,'BBconcrete'));
            obj.X=x;
        end
    end
end
```

Comment: Thanks for your prompt response, and it surely solves the problem.  Based on your answer, I think I don't even need to declare X as an 'abstract' property in AA, right?  It makes me wonder what does abstract properties do...

Comment: With a weak typed language like Matlab, you are never forced to use such features.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Daniel's answer, I would suggest that attempting to redefine the type in AAConcrete for X is your problem.  either remove the type definition in AA, or (my suggestion) remove it in AAConcrete, and use a set.X function to restrict the type in AA Concrete:

```
function set.X(obj, value);
    validateattributes(value, 'BBConcrete', {'nonempty'});
    obj.X = value;
end;
```